# Python matplotlib: Change axis labels/legend from bold to regular weight

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to make some publication-quality plots, but I have encountered a small problem. It seems by default that matplotlib axis labels and legend entries are weighted heavier than the axis tick marks. Is there anyway to force the axis labels/legend entries to be the same weight as the tick marks?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text',usetex=True)
font = {'family':'serif','size':16}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':14})

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
p1, = plt.plot(x,y)
p2, = plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.xlabel('x-Axis')
plt.ylabel('y-Axis')
plt.legend([p1,p2],['Sin(x)','x$^2$'])
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.savefig('Test.eps',bbox_inches='tight',format='eps')
plt.show()
```

I can use math-mode, but the problem (annoyance) is when I have a sentence for a label, i.e.,

```
plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{This is the x-axis}$')
```

which squishes it all together. I can fix it by using

```
plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{This\: is\: the\: x-axis}$')
```

but that needs a lot of punctuation. I was hoping there was something that I could change that would allow me to bypass the `\mathrm{}` format, and use standard TeX format.

The other option I tried, was using `\text` instead of `\mathrm`, but it seems that Python's interpreter doesn't recognize this without loading the package amsmath. I have also tried:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text',usetex=True)
font = {'family':'serif','size':16}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':14})
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'\usepackage{amsmath}']

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
p1, = plt.plot(x,y)
p2, = plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.xlabel(r'$\text{this is the x-Axis}$')
plt.ylabel('$y-Axis$')
plt.legend([p1,p2],['Sin(x)','x$^2$'])
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.savefig('Test.eps',bbox_inches='tight',format='eps')
plt.show()
```

This doesn't return the desired result either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answer provides a work-around to the problem... However, the problem is very specific to matplotlib and the implementation of the LateX backend.

First of all, the `rc` parameter controlling the font weight of the axis labels is `'axes.labelweight'`, which by default is set to `u'normal'`. This means that the labels *should already be* in regular weight.

The reason why the font appears to be bold can be found in [`matplotlib/texmanager.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/texmanager.py):

1. The font family is chosen by `'font.family'`, in the case of the OP, this is `serif`.
2. Then, the array `'font.<font.family>'` (here: `font.serif`) is evaluated, and the declaration of all fonts is added to the LateX preamble. Among those declarations is the line

   ```
   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pnc}
   ```

   which sets the default to New Century School Book [which appears to be a bold version of Computer Modern Roman](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/~rudl/latex/fonts.pdf).

In conclusion, the shortest way to solve the problem is to set `font.serif` to contain only Computer Modern Roman:

```
font = {'family':'serif','size':16, 'serif': ['computer modern roman']}
```

This has the additional benefit that it works for **all** elements, even for labels and other captions - without dirty tricks using the math mode: 
[image]

---

Here is the complete code to generate the plot:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text',usetex=True)
#font = {'family':'serif','size':16}
font = {'family':'serif','size':16, 'serif': ['computer modern roman']}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':14})
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'\usepackage{amsmath}']

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
p1, = plt.plot(x,y)
p2, = plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.xlabel(r'$\text{this is the x-Axis}$')
plt.ylabel('$y-Axis$')
plt.legend([p1,p2],['Sin(x)','x$^2$'])
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.savefig('Test.eps',bbox_inches='tight',format='eps')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used for the plot? If I understand you correctly, all labels (axis and legend) were typed similarly to `('label entry')` and the only math mode entry was the y-label `('$y-axis$')`. If that's the case, then this is a great solution!

Comment: The plot was generated exactly from your code, only the highlighted line was changed!

Comment: I came across this answer while attempting to get LaTeX fonts in matplotlib. It turned out that I had to replace `'computer modern roman'` with `'cmr10`' which appears to have had the correct effect.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text',usetex=True)
font = {'family':'serif','size':16}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':14})

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
p1, = plt.plot(x,y)
p2, = plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{This is the }x\mathrm{-axis}$'.replace(' ','\: '))
plt.ylabel('$y\mathrm{-axis}$')
plt.legend([p1,p2],['$\sin(x)$','$x^2$'], loc='best')
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.15)
plt.savefig('Test.eps',bbox_inches='tight',format='eps')
plt.show()
```

This uses

```
plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{This is the }x\mathrm{-axis}$'.replace(' ','\: '))
```

to replace spaces with `'\: '`. TeX gurus may object to this however. You may want to ask on [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) if there is a better way.