# Consistent fonts between matplotlib and latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm desperately trying to find 'the easiest way' to obtain identically looking text in my matplotlib figures and my latex document.

So far my strategy is to:

- set an explicit width for my Latex figures and set the same size with Matplotlib. That way setting a font size in mpl equal to the Latex font size should be a first step
- use the `usetex = True` option in mpl. I understand that this should make mpl use Latex for ALL text processing in the figure (title, labels, text, annotation, etc.).

My problem is that in the end I still can't set the fonts as I'd like to.

Here is an example where the horizontal axis label font is clearly different from the ticks labels, which I'm confident are identical to the text of my latex document.

Here is the code that generated the figure:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with plt.style.context('journal'):
  fig_size = [3.4, 2.1]
  fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=fig_size)
  ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
  ax1.plot([1,2,3,4,5], '+--')
  ax1.set_xlabel(r'1 2 3 4.0 intensity [$10^{13}p$]')
  plt.tight_layout()
  fig.savefig('test.png') # I saved to png for SO but the goal is eps
```

and my `journal` mpl stylesheet is

```
backend: PS
text.usetex: True
text.latex.unicode: True
font.family: lmodern # apparently no effect as usetex is true anyway
font.size: 10
axes.titlesize: 10
axes.labelsize: 10
axes.unicode_minus: True
axes.linewidth: 1
legend.fontsize: 10
xtick.labelsize: 10
xtick.major.size: 4
xtick.major.width: 0.5
ytick.labelsize: 10
lines.linewidth: 1.5
lines.markersize: 3
figure.titleweight: normal
savefig.dpi: 600
```

[image]

Additionally, I'm not even sure that I'm able to choose/switch from Computer Modern to Latin Modern, partly because my eyes can't distinguish them (which in a way makes the issue irrelevant, but you know... geeks...).

Comment: I'm posting an answer that seems to be solving my issue, however I'm still curious to have feedback on my question "in general".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using this for years without a problem; simply specifying the same font in the `text.latex preamble` as I'm using in my LaTeX document, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', size=14)
rc('legend', fontsize=13)
rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{cmbright}')

pl.figure()
pl.plot([0,1], [0,1], label=r'$\theta_{\phi}^3$')
pl.legend(frameon=False, loc=2)
pl.xlabel(r'change of $\widehat{\phi}$')
pl.ylabel(r'change of $\theta_{\phi}^3$')
```

[image]

*edit* I've never used stylesheet before, but this seems to work as well when I put it in an empty stylesheet:

```
text.usetex: True
font.size: 14
legend.fontsize: 13
text.latex.preamble: \usepackage{cmbright}
```

Comment: I'm very happy it's that simple and at the same time I'm so upset that I spent the afternoon on that...

Comment: Do you know how this could be specified also in a stylesheet?

Comment: I didn't know until today that matplotlib has/had stylesheets :)

Comment: It seems to work as well with a stylesheet, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some insane reason the font was switched to *New Century School Book*. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30731054/420892).

I'm still not sure what is happening but it seems that the **presence** of the `font.serif` option changes the behaviour, irrespective of what is actually in `font.family` or in `font.serif`. Here is an example (other options as in the question):

```
backend: PS
text.usetex: True
text.latex.unicode: True
font.family: xyzxyz
font.serif: abcabc # Comment this out
```

Which gives the following, where the axis label is using the same font as the tick labels. Commenting out the `font.serif` line produces the plot of the initial question.

[image]