# Matplotlib's TeX implementation searched for a file named 'cmbr10.tfm' in your texmf tree, but could not find it

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am getting the error: `FileNotFoundError: Matplotlib's TeX implementation searched for a file named 'cmbr10.tfm' in your texmf tree, but could not find it` when I try to use matplolib with latex with a non-default font.

The exact filename changes depending on which font I try to use. I have checked that my latex install works with the desired package and that my PATH is set correctly. I also reinstalled texlive in case that was the source of the problem. The "missing" file is located in a sub-directory of `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm`.
I've seen several similar issues online, but none seem to be giving this exact error.

Any ideas?

MWE from here: [Consistent fonts between matplotlib and latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942210/consistent-fonts-between-matplotlib-and-latex)

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', size=14)
rc('legend', fontsize=13)
rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{cmbright}')

pl.figure()
pl.plot([0,1], [0,1], label=r'$\theta_{\phi}^3$')
pl.legend(frameon=False, loc=2)
pl.xlabel(r'change of $\widehat{\phi}$')
pl.ylabel(r'change of $\theta_{\phi}^3$')
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code that executed w.o any error and, afaict, the labels are typeset in CM Bright.  Not reproducible.

Comment: The code works fine for me, too.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the path to `kpsewhich.lua` was set incorrectly.